# Flutter - How to make SvgPicture.asset() take full screen inside of Slack with main parent Scaffold without Appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, flutter-layout

I want to make the SvgPicture take full width and height. Here is the current solution.

I have currently used `double.infinity` for width and height. However, I want to make it use the `LayoutBuilder`'s constraints to make the image full width and height.

```dart
LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (layoutBuilderContext, constraints) {                  
                  return Stack(
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/images/welcome/bg-welcome-screen.svg',
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: double.infinity,
                      ),
                  ]),
              })
```

However, that is not able to happen using `constraints.maxWidth` and `constraints.maxHeight` for sizing the `SvgPicture`. It takes full height but failes to take full width.

How can I size the image to full width without using `double.infinity` if possible. I really want it to take the full screen width and height as it is a background image for the app.

Answer (score 0):

To take full size of stack use `Positioned.fill`, And to size the Stack widget, wrap `Stack` with `SizedBox`

```dart
  SizedBox(
   width: constraints.maxWidth,
   height:constraints.maxHeight, 
    child: Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Text(""),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

It is better to use `LayoutBuilder` on top level widget like scaffold's body for getting body size.

More about [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)

Comment: Where is `constraints` coming from in this example?

Comment: `LayoutBuilder` as on question included

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using BoxFit.fill? That will fill the target width and height by distorting the image's original aspect ratio.

Comment: I have set it to BoxFit.cover. I do not want it to distort. I want it to be set to cover, rather take whole width and height of screen as it is a background image.

Comment: In that case, your code should also be good with constraints.maxHeight and constraints.maxWidth, can you add a screenshot of its result please?